# How to import Excel file and skip dynamic footer?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have to upload an Excel template needed to skip header and footer rows.  It's easier to skip header but I have been struggled to skip the footer because not fixed at a particular number of rows.  This Excel file will be uploaded to a SQL Server table.

Is it a good way to check the COL1 with "NOTE:"?  Anyone can provide some clues?
Thanks in advance.

The footer is looking like:

```
NOTE:
This is a long sentence note - line 1
This is a long sentence note - line 2
This is a long sentence note - line 3
This is a long sentence note - line 4
```

Import the Export file with SSIS.

Comment: The best option for you is if the data is broken out into tables wherein Sheet1 is TblHeader ,TblBody, TblFooter. Then instead of selecting `Sheet1$` you can select `TblBody`. Otherwise, you're writing code. You'll need an Asynchronous Script Component. Async because once you encounter Row.Col1 == "NOTE:" then you will send no further rows downstream regardless of how many inbound rows you receive.

Answer (score 0):

If the footer always starts with the word "NOTE:" in the COL1, you can definitely use it as a marker to skip the footer rows during the data upload.

You can use a the Conditional Split transformation with a condition to filter out rows where COL1 starts with "NOTE:" :

````
  ```
  LEFT([COL1], 5) != "NOTE:"
  ```
````

Here, `LEFT([COL1], 5)` takes the first five characters of the `COL1` value, and we are checking if it is not equal to "NOTE:".

Then, connect the output of the Conditional Split (for rows that do not match the "NOTE:" condition) to an OLE DB Destination (or your preferred destination). And configure the OLE DB Destination to point to your SQL Server table and map the columns from the Excel Source to the table columns.